Inaccessible File
I was trying to create a simple input and output terminal when my program was halted by two errors.
This one from the webpage.
Your file couldn't be accessed
It may have been moved, edited or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
and this from VSCode
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"


Here is the code.


 
   function spitBack(fieldId){
    var spit = document.getElementById(fieldId).value;
    alert(spit + " is among us.");

   }
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Personal Logs</h1>
    <h1>The Arrangement</h1>
    <p>I am XXXX XXXXXXXX, a refugee of XXXXX as a member of the X.X. XXXXX force.<br>I vow to protect the xxxxxxxxxxxxx interests.</p>
    <form action="send-email.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="40" placeholder="input" id="Input">
       <input type="image" src="amongus/amonus.webp" alt="amongus" width="72" height="72"  onclick="spitBack('Input');">
       Press Red Boi to enter
    </form>
  </body>
</html>



The core of the problem is that after i call the function i get the two errors in their respective applications and how to make it stop. My guess is that the program doesn't have the right keyword(s) to tell it to return me back to the state of the webpage before i pressed the amongus image. I searched the web and they said it was some sort of google chrome browser version or extension compatibility issue.
I checked my only extension to see if it was the problem. It was not and my browser works fine when i remove the button and text box code.
Thanks for any help and i am a beginner if you think the code looks messy.

First, you need a web server to run PHP code, you cannot use the file:/// protocol. Luckily PHP comes with a built-in development server. Second, it seems your send-email.php does not exist where you think it does

Also, <input type="image"> acts as a submit button when you click it
